# Find the minimum value from a Firebase realtime database?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get my head around Javascript and use it to read a realtime database from Firebase. I can read the data from Firebase and display it on my HTML page but i now want to do some basic analysis on the data such as finding the minimum key value.

However, any time i try to use things like the `Math.min()` function or use for loops to analyze the data i just get a summary essentially of how many times each value appears or a load of '0's. Any help making sense of this is really appreciated.

```
function SmallestValue(data, prevChildKey) { 
    const datapoint = data.val();  // Extracting the contents of the call to the database object and assigning it to variable datapoint
    const key_vals = Object.values(datapoint) // I think this gives me a nested array of key values values
    y=(Math.min(...key_vals));
    console.log(y);  // The frequency of each value appears in the console

    const new_array =[];    //other option also tried was a for loop create a new array of just the values
    for (let i=0; i<key_vals.length; i++){
        var innerarraylength = key_vals[i].length;
        for (let j=0; j<innerarraylength; j++){
         
        console.log('['+i+','+j+']='+key_vals[i][j]);
        console.log(i);
        x.push(nested[i]);
    }
    
    console.log(x)
}
```

[image: Firebase Realtime Database]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your database structure?

Comment: There is a link to a screenshot of the database in Firebase in the original post now. In my mind, the data from the database is saved as an object/array in the variable datapoint. In the key_vals variable, depending on if i use Object.keys or Object.values i will see either the string 'Temps' or the number '24' or whatever the number is. I then think the key_vals variable is storing the numbers i want to analyse as a nested array, so in the form [ [all the numbers] ]. But from there i can't understand the outputs i am getting